# d3.js ParseDate Questions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to learn/re-create [this lovely chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4679202) and I have been running into a problem with the data. I was examining the parseDate call in the d3.tsv part (line 85). I can't understand why the graph fails to work if I remove line 86. Shouldn't it just use the quarter column as a string? If I were trying to recreate this graph with different data, say a (1)category (2)unique identified and (3)a number. what would I have to add so that it will recognize it as a string?

The code is straight from the site, but I'll post it here too!

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.group-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-anchor: end;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

</style>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="multiples" checked> Multiples</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="stacked"> Stacked</label>
</form>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse,
    formatYear = d3.format("02d"),
    formatDate = function(d) { return "Q" + ((d.getMonth() / 3 | 0) + 1) + formatYear(d.getFullYear() % 100); };

var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .2);

var y1 = d3.scale.linear();

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 0);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(formatDate);

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.group; });

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .out(function(d, y0) { d.valueOffset = y0; });

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  var dataByGroup = nest.entries(data);

  stack(dataByGroup);
  x.domain(dataByGroup[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y0.domain(dataByGroup.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
  y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]).range([y0.rangeBand(), 0]);

  var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
      .data(dataByGroup)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "group")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + ")"; });

  group.append("text")
      .attr("class", "group-label")
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.values[0].value / 2); })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return "Group " + d.key; });

  group.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y0.rangeBand() - y1(d.value); });

  group.filter(function(d, i) { return !i; }).append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y0.rangeBand() + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", change);

  var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("input[value=\"stacked\"]").property("checked", true).each(change);
  }, 2000);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if (this.value === "multiples") transitionMultiples();
    else transitionStacked();
  }

  function transitionMultiples() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
        g = t.selectAll(".group").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y0(d.key) + ")"; });
    g.selectAll("rect").attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.value); });
    g.select(".group-label").attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.values[0].value / 2); })
  }

  function transitionStacked() {
    var t = svg.transition().duration(750),
        g = t.selectAll(".group").attr("transform", "translate(0," + y0(y0.domain()[0]) + ")");
    g.selectAll("rect").attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.value + d.valueOffset); });
    g.select(".group-label").attr("y", function(d) { return y1(d.values[0].value / 2 + d.values[0].valueOffset); })
  }
});
```

and

```
</script>

group   date    value
1   2008-01 10
1   2008-04 8
1   2008-07 14
1   2008-10 9
1   2009-01 10
1   2009-04 8
1   2009-07 14
1   2009-10 9
2   2008-01 3
2   2008-04 3.5
2   2008-07 5
2   2008-10 11
2   2009-01 3
2   2009-04 3.5
2   2009-07 4.5
2   2009-10 10.5
3   2008-01 10
3   2008-04 8
3   2008-07 14
3   2008-10 9
3   2009-01 10
3   2009-04 8
3   2009-07 14
3   2009-10 9
4   2008-01 3
4   2008-04 3.5
4   2008-07 5
4   2008-10 11
4   2009-01 3
4   2009-04 3.5
4   2009-07 4.5
4   2009-10 10.5
```

Any insight you have is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you delete the parseDate, the `.tickFormat(formatDate)` on your xAxis does not work anymore as `formatDate` processes the values as dates and not as strings. if you disable the `tickFormat`and the `parseDate` in the tsv-section the graph should work as before.

in this way you should also be able to use your data as string without further adjustments (depending on your data of course).

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! So if I delete those lines, the original data works perfectly, but if I begin to enter my own data the graph either 1. doesn't initialize or 2. the data becomes one blob. I kept the category heads the same, so there isn't an issue there...

If the data was like
1 Person X  0.056
2 Person X  0.4
3 Person X  0.7
4 Person X  0.02
1 Person Y  0.5
2 Person Y  0.3
3 Person Y  0.2
4 Person Y  0.05

Comment: is the data-file properly formatted? tsv expects a tab-seperated data-file. i copied the code here [http://jsbin.com/dedimono/1/](http://jsbin.com/dedimono/1/), it does work with the data you provided (to simplify matters i put the data directly into a variable at the start of the script). you should be able to experiment with this code, maybe it helps.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was, but apparently I was wrong. Thanks so much for all your help; it is greatly appreciated.